# What is the "===" operator for?

Tags: operators

I once encountered an operator "===". But I don remember what it was.. or where do we use it .. or is there any such a kind of operator ? where is it used ??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In PHP, JavaScript, ECMAScript, ActionScript 3.0, and a number of other similar, dynamic languages, there are two types of equality checks: == (non-strict equality) and === (strict equality). To show an example:

```
5 == "5"   // yep, these are equal, because "5" becomes 5 when converted to int
5 === "5"  // nope, these have a different type
```

Basically, whenever you use ==, you risk automatic type conversions. Using === ensures that the values are logically equal AND the types of the objects are also equal.

Comment: Is there any difference between Javascript and ECMAScript?

Comment: @Turtle, yes. ECMAScript is the language standardization effort on which JavaScript is now based (JavaScript came first), and there are many languages -- not just JavaScript -- that derive their core syntax from ECMAScript but then add other elements or constructs (e.g. ActionScript 3.0). The key difference between JavaScript and ECMAScript, is that JavaScript is ECMAScript as it occurs in practice... i.e., how browsers actually implement ECMAScript (such as deviations from the standard, extensions, etc.)

Comment: You made a typo on the second example, should be `5 === "5"` instead of `5 === 5`.

Answer (score 16):

In JavaScript, `==` does type coercion, while `===`, the "strict equality" operator does not.  For example:

```
"1" == 1; // true
"1" === 1; // false
```

There is also a corresponding strict inequality operator, `!==`.

Answer (score 7):

Its used in JavaScript, PHP and may be more (which I may not have encountered yet!), it is used to compare if both the compared things are of same object type as well as have same value.

Comment: Not only JS. Also in a lot other languages.

Answer (score 3):

> "==="  operator is used to check the
>   values are equal as well as same type.

Example

```
$a === $b    if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.
```

Answer (score 2):

It usually tests if two objects are the same. ie. not if they have the same value(s) but if they really are the same object.

Answer (score 1):

=== is equality, at least in PHP

[Here is a link](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/406_Assignment-equality-and-identity-in-PHP.html) that helps explain thsi

Comment: And in Prolog too, as I recall. I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, triple equals is the operator (implicitly) used by the `case/when` construct to determine when an object "falls within" a particular case.  For example, Ruby has a concept of "Range" objects; `1..10` means "all of the values between 1 and 10, inclusive."  So `3 == 1..10' is false, since the 3 is a number and the 1..10 is a Range.  But,

`3 === 1..10` returns true, since 3 is *in* that range.

case/when uses this when deciding which case an arguments belongs to.  So,

```
case a
  when (1..10)
    puts "This is a valid rating"
  else
    puts "invalid"
  end
```

works as expected.